# Partial Derivative of $x^y$

Tags: derivatives

> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}x^y$$

$x^y=e^{ln(x)^y}=e^{y*ln(x)}$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}e^{y\cdot ln(x)}=e^{y\cdot ln(x)}\cdot\frac{y}{x}=x^y\cdot\frac{y}{x}=x^{y-1}\cdot y$$

But the [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive%20x%5Ey%20with%20respect%20to%20x) is different , where did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the correct answer. WolframAlpha thinks $y$ is a function of $x$, which is why it gives the answer it does. [Try using another variable like $t$ instead of $y$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate%20x%5Et%20with%20respect%20to%20x) and you'll see that WolframAlpha gives the right answer.

As a side note, I noticed that the query you typed into WolframAlpha was "derive x^y with respect to x". The process of finding a derivative is *differentiation*, not derivation, so it would be more correct to ask "WolframAlpha to "differentiate x^y with respect to x". The two terms are (incorrectly) used interchangeably so often that WolframAlpha knows you mean "differentiate" when you say "derive".

Answer (score 2):

You didn't get it wrong: Wolfram Alpha just doesn't know that $y$ doesn't depend on $x$.

If it did, then the term that comes from using the product rule would be $$x \log(x) y'=0$$